# JQuery in PHP CHECKED

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a problem and i do not find where it is, I explain to you I have a page.php which integrates a form.php and in this page.php I have a page1.php which is integrating also and which also has the form.php, and in this form I have Checkbox only my functions jquery works fine with pahe.php but not with page1.php and I do not understand why

page.php

```
<div class="left" style="float: left;">
   <?php include('C_User_file/Planning/Form/Start/FStartT1.php'); ?>
</div>
```

page1.php

```
 <div class="left" style="float: left;">
    <?php include('C_User_file/Planning/Form/Start/FStartT1.php'); ?>
</div>
```

FStartT1.php

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" value="1"  checked="checked" name="ALL1">
   ALL
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" value="1" name="FMS1">
  FMS
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox3" value="1" name="CPT1">
  CPT
</label>
```

jquery.js

```
$("#cbox1" ).click(function(){
  $('input[name=ALL1]').attr('checked', true);
  $('input[name=FMS1]').attr('checked', false);
   $('input[name=CPT1]').attr('checked', false);
});

$("#cbox2" ).click(function(){
  $('input[name=ALL1]').attr('checked', false);
  $('input[name=FMS1]').attr('checked', true);
  $('input[name=CPT1]').attr('checked', false);
});

$("#cbox3" ).click(function(){
  $('input[name=ALL1]').attr('checked', false);
  $('input[name=FMS1]').attr('checked', false);
  $('input[name=CPT1]').attr('checked', true);
});
```

On page.php works fine but on page1.php this does not work at all, thanks for your help

Be careful, my page1.php is included in page.php

Comment: you are including the same file twice, thats why the conflict

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code, I got to know one thig.
The `FStartT1.php` i.e your FORM which is being imported 2 times.

So technically you have 2 form fields when the page is loaded. If you have doubt, just hit `ctr+u` on chrome and check the page source. You find 2 forms.
The means the IDs are duplicating. SO jQuery is unable to process it. IDs must be unique.
So,the following sections won't work.

```
$("#cbox1" ).click(function(){

});

$("#cbox2" ).click(function(){

});

$("#cbox3" ).click(function(){

});
```

Solution: 
Make it a class instead of ID. And call like this

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="cbox1" value="1"  checked="checked" name="ALL1">
   ALL
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="cbox2" value="1" name="FMS1">
  FMS
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="cbox3" value="1" name="CPT1">
  CPT
</label>
```

And in your jQuery,

```
$(".cbox1" ).click(function(){

});

$(".cbox2" ).click(function(){

});

$(.cbox3" ).click(function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below jQuery:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]" ).click(function(){
  $("input[type=checkbox]" ).each(function(){
   $(this).attr('checked', false);
 });
 $(this).attr('checked', true);
});
```

Try the above jquery code.

**Explanation:**

You are using the jquery selector as id and you are including the page1.php in page.php and both page has included FStartT1.php page. So you have same checkboxes with same id twice.

That's why your jquery code is working for first one not for second one.

Remember the id must be identical for HTML page and for jQuery also. 
And I have right a generic jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative Solution: Radio fields

Is there any reason for you not to use radio fields?

If someone (for whatever reason) has JavaScript disabled in their browsers settings, that person would be able to check and combination of your checkboxes.

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" class="cbox1" value="1"  checked="checked" name="events">
   ALL
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" class="cbox2" value="1" name="events">
  FMS
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" class="cbox3" value="1" name="events">
  CPT
</label>
```